# Raster masking keep old extent

Tags: qgis, raster, clip, saga, masking

I want to clip a raster file using for mask other raster file and in SAGA GIS provider tool QGIS  `QGIS Processing | Raster Tools | raster masking` .

I realized the new masking file keeps in the metadata the original data from extent  and not the new extent coordinates.

How can I fix that ?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you need to use the `Clip Rasters` tool, not the `Raster Masking` tool. Another tool to use is `Clip Raster by Mask Layer`. It gives you the option to set the extent of the raster to the mask layer.

Comment: @ahmadhanb that works with vectors layers,i need to clip with other raster layer

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot of how the clip raster looks like? It will be easier to understand the issue you are facing.